# Is it safe to rename, delete or disable system/bin/mediaserver?

Tags: file-system, unbricking, logging, media-scanner, disable-app

mediaserver is constantly running in the background eating up CPU.

I don't care at this point if I don't get to use the gallery app and I'm fed up with having to reboot every time I hop out of my car.

While I'm at it, I have the same question/issue with logcat2.

---

Edit: I deleted mediaserver and logcat, booted into recovery, fixed permissions, deleted dalvik and cache and am stuck on `"Android is upgrading... Starting Apps."` (Recovery isn't an issue but having some method of effectively disabling the processes is necessary)

Any advice is appreciated. It's an HTC One m7 running ViperOne 6.2.1.

I have already tried [Rescan Media ROOT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addz.mediascannerroot&hl=en) & [Stop Log ☆Root☆](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.stoplog&hl=en) and Netflix still causes these processes to spin out of out control. Perhaps this is related to [Greenify's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) hibernation (active for Netflix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly speculation, but mediaserver is probably what is used to play all and any sound on android. Some app was probably using mediaserver inappropriately, causing it to show as using excessive battery.

logcat2 is probably the process used for logging output, and is where many debug and error messages are sent to.

Outright deleting them probably wasn't smart. Do you have a custom recovery installed? What phone is this? Your best bet is probably to restore those files. If you don't have them anymore, get them from an identical device.

Comment: Yes I was able to restore the system partition with TWRP so I'm right back where I started. It is triggered by netflix/MHL connection.

Comment: Updated rom and so far no issues. I will also concur that deleting them is generally not the correct approach.